# embeds[0].author.icon_url: Scheme "null" is not supported. discord.js V13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I set  a welcomer in my bot (I work with discord.js v13) event when a member join the guild send a embed but when the joined member don't have a avatar i get this error can anyone help

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'iconURL')
    at Captcha.present (/root/gentlemen/node_modules/discord.js-captcha/src/index.js:202:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embeds[0].author.icon_url: Scheme "null" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').
```

Comment: Can you provide any code?

Comment: Please provide the code, or more details about the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `<User>.displayAvatarURL()` this allows you to get user avatart even if its default